# setting the location of the user in <s:select>

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, struts2

I have a strut select tag and I have a list of countries in my drop down list and I want when ever a user access the page, the country in which user is gets auto-selected

here is my JSP:

```
<s:select 
   name="dropdown"
   list="countries"
   listKey="value"
   listValue="key"
   id="listofcountries"
   value="%{visitor_country}"
   onchange="countryname();"
/>
```

In the select tag "countries" is a hashmap coming from an action class and has list of countries.

What i have done till now is, i have got the user's location but the only thing is i am not able to set the country into the select tag,

how i am getting the user location

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAp04yNttlQq-7b4aZI_jL5hQYPm-xtd00hTQOC0OXpAMO40FHAxQMnH50uBbWoKVHwgpklyirDEregg"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(google.loader.ClientLocation)
    {          
        visitor_country = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country;
        document.getElementById('yourinfo').innerHTML ='<p>Location: '  + visitor_country +'</p>';
    }


</script>
```

Help is needed to set this `visitor_country` into the `<s:select>`

Comment: You need to set the value of the select to the country; you don't appear to even attempt this.

Comment: @DaveNewton ya actually i am not able to do it thats y i posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code under the `visitor_country`. Assume the key and value is the same in the list.

```
$('#listofcountries').append($("<option/>", {
    value: visitor_country,
    text: visitor_country
}));
```

Comment: no its not working nothing happened..
btw where you wanted me to add the code may be i added it wrong

Comment: you need struts2-jquery plugin

Comment: i have jar for struts 2 and i have included script source for jquery

Comment: this is not enough